# Rewriting CSS paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked around a lot, but can't find anything that really explains much.  I've used htaccess rewrites before without much issue, but I can't seem to find where this one's failing. I think it has something to do with the initial (original) URL, but I can't seem to find a working combination.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/site/vnd/style/main.css?p=desktop">
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^style/([A-Z]+\.css)\?p=(.*)$ style/$2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Expected redirect (where the file actually lives):

```
style/desktop/main.css
```

In regex testers it splits and re-creates it just fine, but I can't see what Apache sees, so it's hard to debug.  I've tried combinations of absolute and relative paths, trailing and no-trailing slashes, etc.

In the console, a 404 is being output, telling me that the redirect isn't working at all, and is still looking for the original URL. Headers:

```
Request URL: http://localhost/Patterns/mvc/style/main.css?p=desktop
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule`s are not capable of picking up query strings. You'll need to use a condition to capture it, and pass it  on accordingly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)
RewriteRule ^style/([a-z]+)\.css$ style/%1/$1.css [R=301,L,NC]
```

Notice that I have moved the `p` key to the `QUERY_STRING` condition, and that I have added the `NC` flag to the rule (which means that it will ignore the case of the string).

Comment: Oh wow.  How have I never come across this before?! Thank you!

Comment: Not many people have - and it's a common question that many people miss, because they don't know what to look for. Glad it works for you.